# how a device driver is loaded into linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anyone tell, how a device driver is loaded into linux kernel? means the function call flow. who invokes what? etc., for static and pnp drivers. with some example would be great, like insert USB pen drive kind of stuff.
THanks

Comment: Just enable the kgdb and see the flow.

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, to be loaded in the kernel, the driver must be compiled as module.
- The compiled module will have **.ko** extension.
- The usual location for modules is inside the */lib/modules* directory.
- You can have a list of all inserted modules with command **lsmod**.
- The module is loaded when the system or the user inserts the module (command **insmod** or **modprobe**)
- The **module_init()** function specifies which is the function to be invoked when the module is inserted:

  ```
  static int __init hello_init(void)
  {
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world!\n");
      return 0;
  }
  module_init(hello_init);
  ```
- Similarly, the function **module_exit()** specifies the function to be executed when the module is unloaded
- The function is defined **static** because it shouldn't be visible outside of the file
- The **__init** token tells the kernel that the function can be dropped after the module is loaded
- The kernel function **sys_init_module()**:

  - allocates (through **vmalloc()**) the memory to hold the module;
  - copies the module into that memory region;
  - resolves kernel references in the module via the kernel symbol table (works like the linker *ld*)
  - calls the module's initialization function.